# Java Child Window: Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I have two `JFrames` (mainFrame.java & child.java) designed in NetBeans editor. I want to call second `JFrame` from the first frame as a child window. How can I call it?

Comment: I want to call child.java after clicking a button in mainFrame.java @LewsTherin .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- don't use two [JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), [the best suggestion why not, or e.i. is answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/714968) by `@Andrew Thompson`
- have look at [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)
- to check [JDialog(Dialog owner, boolean modal)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29) or [ModalityTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make the object of the first frame and then call it in the second frame.

```
firstframe fm = new firstframe();
fm.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to have a main Window with child/children window inside of it. If this is so, check out the below code.

Screen Shot: [image]

```
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
/**
 * Sample demonstrates using JInternalFrame as a child window of a main
 * JFrame window  TicTacToe class extends JInternalFrame.
 * @author Kirk
 *
*/
public class BoardBuilder extends JFrame {

    private TicTacToe board;
    JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();

    public BoardBuilder() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               board = new TicTacToe("TicToc Toe", true);
               board.setSize(250, 250);
               board.setClosable(true);
               board.setIconifiable(true);
               board.setDefaultCloseOperation(TicTacToe.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
               if (!board.isVisible())
                   board.setVisible(true);

               desktopPane.add(board);
               add(desktopPane);
           }
       });

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       BoardBuilder builderBoard = new BoardBuilder();
       builderBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
       builderBoard.setSize(640, 480);
       builderBoard.setVisible(true);

    }

   }
```

to call the child window  place this code block in a button Click event Listener

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
               board = new TicTacToe("TicToc Toe", true);
               board.setSize(250, 250);
               board.setClosable(true);
               board.setIconifiable(true);
               board.setDefaultCloseOperation(TicTacToe.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
               if (!board.isVisible())
                   board.setVisible(true);

               desktopPane.add(board);
               add(desktopPane);
           }
       });
```

For future info check out this link [docs.oracle-InternalFrames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)